# Retrieving default UI colors on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uicolor

PREAMBLE: since iOS 13 with its dark theme, there's a proper notion of system colors on iOS. See the `UIColor` class.

---

Here's my iPhone project with a XIB file with a regular UIButton on it. The button has a text color - a nice shade of blue, RGB(50, 79, 133) to be precise.

Is there a quick and proper way to retrieve that color value in runtime? Not the color of this particular button, but the default text color of UIButtons? Preferably as a `UIColor *` or a `CGColorRef`.

Is there a notion of system colors on iPhone, or this is just a default enforced by the presets in the Interface Builder?

Yes, I can do some elementary math and convert the RGB into the floating-point (UGH!) representation that UIColor uses. Anything more elegant than that?

Answer (score 2):

For the UIColor problem may I suggest adding a category to UIColor, like this:

**UIColor+Extras.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor(Extras)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRGBA:(NSUInteger) rgba;
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRGB:(NSUInteger) rgb;
@end
```

**UIColor+Extras.m**

```
#import "UIColor+Extras.h"

@implementation UIColor(Extras)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRGBA:(NSUInteger) rgba
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(rgba >> 24) / 255.0f green:(0xff & ( rgba >> 16)) / 255.0f blue:(0xff & ( rgba >> 8)) / 255.0f alpha:(0xff & rgba) / 255.0f];
}

+ (UIColor *)colorWithRGB:(NSUInteger) rgb
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(rgb >> 16) / 255.0f green:(0xff & ( rgb >> 8)) / 255.0f blue:(0xff & rgb) / 255.0f alpha:1.0];
}
@end
```

This will let you write stuff like `[UIColor colorWithRGBA:0xFF00FFFF]` or `[UIColor colorWithRGB:0xFF00FF]`

As fo the starting color values, some of them are documented in the header files, like UIButton.h, and there are also some colors available as class methods on UIColor, like [UIColor lightTextColor] [UIColor darkTextColor] etc. These are documented in the UIColor class reference.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you want to retrieve the default color there is always:

```
[[button titleLabel] textColor]
```

To get the text color of any button. If you want the default color, create a hidden button and check the text color of it. Not very elegant mind you.

Comment: @Nuoji: the one I'm after is not documented in UIButton.h or UIColor. So the answer is - no such thing, use arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, there is room for stacking up on a lot of utility functions / categories when playing with Cocoa. I suspect the 0-1.0 floating point color is inspired by OpenGL and similar.

Comment: P.S. Added a hack-ish way to get the standard color. This approach obviously works for other components as well, but is very ugly...

Comment: Colours are floating-point on iOS because it inherits from the Mac, where the use of floating-point allows the OS to abstract away details of colour representation and to minimize the errors that are inevitably introduced when changing between colour spaces or blending 2+ colours together. It's very much by design.

Comment: The category over UIColor is an overkill, IMHO. Instead, I'd do something along the lines of `#define RGB(r,g,b) ([UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255. green:(g)/255. blue:(b)/255.])`. This has the advantage of compile-time calculation when used with constant RGB values.

Comment: Well, you could write those categories as inline functions or defines as well. It's just that it looks very consistent with the normal UIColor API. Typically you write `[UIColor color...` and then code complete. If you have the category, you'll get the category-method as a suggestion, otherwise you need to remember you named it RGB or similar. I would suggest that would be extremely uncommon that one is creating new colors so often that the additional indirection of the category makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the default button text color, all you have to do is:

```
label.textColor = [button titleColorForState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can get the other colors by specifying a different UIControlState.

Comment: That's assuming I *have* a button in the first place. Sorry, that's not what I'm after.

Comment: When I used it, I just made a temporary button to get the color from and then got rid of it when I was done.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I know this was a while back, but I ran into it again and noticed this: "Anything more elegant than that?" If elegance is your goal, you may need to switch to another language lul